# where clause with just one single OR statement - strange behavior with and without brackets

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a SQL query like this - (table name replaced but the query is same)

```
select * from MY_TABLE 
where  col1 = 'val1' or
col1 = 'val2'
```

When i ran this in lower environment , the query worked fine but when i ran this in higher environment (PRODUCTION env)

this query is giving me -  all transactions - which satisfy

```
col1 = 'val1'
col1 = 'val2'
col1 = 'val3'
col1 = 'val4'
col1 = 'val5'
```

My table have these five values - so finally i just added the brackets and it fixed the issue - but why it was not reflecting in lower environments

fix is as below

```
select * from MY_TABLE 
where ( col1 = 'val1' or
col1 = 'val2' )
```

I don't need the solution -  but would like to know why this is happening.

I tried searching for it , but no solid answer so far

Comment: is there any more condition ?

Comment: You should be using `col1 in ('val1', 'val2')`.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin -  no , just one OR condition

Comment: If the first query really returns rows with `col1 = 'val3'`, then your DBMS or at least your database is broken (e.g. an index containing complete nonsense). This seems highly unlikely. It is much more likely that your real query has a flaw that your sample query doesn't have.

Comment: "Wrong results" bugs are rare but do happen.  It's possible there is something weird going on with the execution plan that is forcing the usage of an index, but only for one specific query on one database.  Check the execution plan, like with `explain plan for select ...;` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Pay special attention to the "Note" section for any plan management.  Also check the view `DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES` - it's possible (but extremely unlikely) that someone used `DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE` to secretly change the output of a query, but only on one database.

Comment: yes - will check that , thank you